# This simple script chewed up a lot of CPU, why?

Tags: scripts, performance, cpu

I have a remote machine I need to keep an eye on. It's running Ubuntu Studio 22.04 (KDE Plasma). A few weeks ago it crashed and journalctl showed a "Bug" that occurred a couple minutes before the crash. So I wrote a simple script that follows journalctl and if the word "Bug" appears it sends a warning email. I set that script running about 10 days ago. Yesterday, I connected to the machine remotely and checked htop and found that the script was using over 90% of CPU. I killed it and CPU usage dropped back to normal. Here's the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#####################
#   THIS SCRIPT LAUNCHED AT STARTUP, CHECKS journalctl for string "Bug"
######################

while true; do

nohup journalctl --follow | grep -i -q "bug" && mutt -s "ALERT - AirchainPC may be in TROUBLE" -- myemail@gmail.com < bug_issued_by_journalctl.txt &>/dev/null &

done
```

Anything there that might explain the high CPU usage? BTW, I don't think I need that "nohup".

Comment: Just curious: what did you think this script will do? There's a file being redirected to `mutt` which otherwise isn't mentioned in the script at all, so are you just sending yourself the same file as an email infinitely many times?

Comment: @muru I think you gave the answer right there.. 

Comment: Sending the command to the back ground with `&` in a `while true; ...` loop will free the loop immediately resulting in rerunning the command sending hundreds/thousands to the background until your system resources are consumed ... Also detaching it with `nohup` will do the same ... So, remove both and your script should run as you expect it without consuming all your system's resources.

Comment: @ArturMeinild (technically that's not the reason, the problem is the `&` at the end. OP's backgrounding everything in an infinite loop, so it doesn't matter what's going on with `journalctl`, `grep`, or `mutt`, really. I'd like to know how much OP understands shell scripting before attempting an explanation)

Comment: OP (me) is not very skilled at scripting, as can clearly be seen. I'm a community radio station studio engineer trying to keep things running. My intent is to keep an eye on this remote machine's journalctl and get a notification email if the search string occurs. So, this is a crude attempt at that. I think I ran out of inotify watch descriptors due to my infinite looping. Thank you.

Comment: Note that `journalctl` has a `--grep` option, this will avoid some overhead as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please, change your script to something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
journalctl --follow | grep --line-buffered -i bug | while read -r ; do
  mutt -s "ALERT - AirchainPC may be in TROUBLE" -- 'myemail@gmail.com' < bug_issued_by_journalctl.txt
done
```

Here, you are following the journal trying to catch lines containing the "bug" string. If the string is matched, it will be returned by `grep` *immediately* (thanks to the `--line-buffered` option) into the `while` loop. The `read` command will consume each such line and return, so that the body of the `while` statement will be executed at that time.

I don't know what the contents of the `bug_issued_by_journalctl.txt` file are, but I would prefer something dynamically created and containing (part of) the string matched from `journalctl`'s output. In such a case, replace `read -r` with `read -r msg` and use the contents of the `$msg` variable in the mail text. Also, if the script is to be run by another user and/or from another directory, the full path for the above-mentioned file should be used.

Because of the `--follow` option in `journalctl` command, this script will never return. If you want, you can send the script to background  like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_bug () {
  journalctl --follow | grep --line-buffered -i bug | while read -r ; do
    mutt -s "ALERT - AirchainPC may be in TROUBLE" -- 'myemail@gmail.com'
  done
}

check_bug &>/dev/null &
```

A simple advice: Always test interactively first before putting something into background! While testing, you will also want to replace the `&>/dev/null` in the last line, with something like `&>/tmp/check_bug.out`.

---

**Update:** As @G.Sliepen suggested, you may replace the command sequence of

```
journalctl --follow | grep --line-buffered -i bug
```

with

```
journalctl --follow --grep=bug
```

You should read [`man journalctl`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/journalctl.1.html) page though, for *case-sensitivity* and other details.

Comment: Well, thank you very much for the suggested and far more sensible script, and the detailed explanation! I'm just a volunteer at the station yet the pressure is on to keep things running. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the line-buffered option isn’t POSIX (I’m not sure why it’s needed, anyway: something to do with buffering output?).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble on this site, there is no need since _only_ Ubuntu is on topic, so every command is assumed to be for the GNU toolset and, more specifically, for whatever version of any tool is present in Ubuntu.

Comment: @thatjackelliott note that the reason you saw the CPU spike is because you had `while true`. This spams the CPU, and adding a `sleep 1` for  1 second delay, or even a `sleep 0.1` for a 0.1 second delay, to your loop would make everything better. FedKad's solution is much better, of course, but next time you need an infinite loop for a tool that lacks the `--follow` option, add a `sleep` command to the end of it.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `journalctl`'s builtin option `--grep='pattern'` will only search the `MESSAGE=` field and will match case insensitive if the `pattern` is all lowercase or case sensitive otherwise ... So, there might be cases where piping to `/bin/grep` is preferred.